# Sqlite 3 download

Tags: sql, sqlite, dll, exe

I went to the website and saw three links for windows download ok i said.
I watched some tutorials on which of the versions to install but all mentioned the -shell version which no longer is there.

From what I can tell only one of the links is 64-bit the two others are 32-bit.
The problem is one of the 32-bit has all three: A bundle of command-line tools for managing SQLite database files, including the command-line shell program, the sqldiff.exe program, and the sqlite3_analyzer.exe program.

And what is most frustrating is that that 32-bit file is the only one with the .exe the others are -dll.

What do you recommend me to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, the shell was moved into the -tools package.

Comment: Is the -tools package 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: 64-bit Windows is 32-bit compatible.